# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Formatting' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting'

Tags: c#, json.net

I have added these code under WebApiConfig to see the data in Camel Notation

```
var settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Formatting' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting'. An explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast?

Your kind answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's on this line I assume? `settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented` That's must be the wrong Formatting enum. What "using"s do you have at the top of the file? Do you have "using System.Xml.Formatting" ?

Comment: try to use `Formatting` with full reference name like `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented`

Comment: Absolutely I got the error on this line. At the top of the file I have  `using System.Xml` @Rup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`settings.Formatting` is expecting the `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting` type but it's using `System.Xml`. Remove `using System.Xml` if you don't need it. Otherwise, use the fully qualifying name:

`settings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;`